# Chrome corrupting binary file download by converting to UTF-8

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask, utf-8

I've currently been assigned to maintain an application written with Flask. Currently I'm trying to add a feature that allows users to download a pre-generated excel file, however, whenever I try to send it, my browser appears to re-encode the file in UTF-8 which causes multibyte characters to be added, which corrupts the file.

File downloaded with wget:

```
(venv) luke@ubuntu:~$ hexdump -C wget.xlsx | head -n 2
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00  08 00 06 06 fb 4a 1f 23  |PK...........J.#|
00000010  cf 03 c0 00 00 00 13 02  00 00 0b 00 00 00 5f 72  |.............._r|
```

The file downloaded with Chrome (notice the `EF BF BD` sequences?)

```
(venv) luke@ubuntu:~$ hexdump -C chrome.xlsx | head -n 2
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00  08 00 ef bf bd 03 ef bf  |PK..............|
00000010  bd 4a 1f 23 ef bf bd 03  ef bf bd 00 00 00 13 02  |.J.#............|
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? This is the code I'm using:

```
data = b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00}\x0c\xfbJ\x1f#\xcf\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x13\x02\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
send_file(BytesIO(data), attachment_filename="x.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

Related issue: [Encoding problems trying to send a binary file using flask_restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770864/encoding-problems-trying-to-send-a-binary-file-using-flask-restful)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome was expecting to receive utf-8 encoded text, and found some bytes that couldn't be interpreted as valid utf-8 encoding of a char - which is normal, because your file is binary. So it replaced these invalid bytes with `EF BF BD`, the utf-8 encoding of the Unicode replacement character. The `content-type` header you send is probably `text/....`. Maybe try something like `Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: The issue ended up being in the front-end, the code which was used to download the file interpreted the file as a string, which converted it to UTF-8, fixed by setting the `responseType` in the AngularJS `$http` call to `'arraybuffer'`, thanks for the help though